# Помощь в понимании

Tags: python

Кто может построчно расписать что делает функция (принцип работы), я не могу разобраться.

```
from collections import deque
def dbl_linear(n):
    queue = [1]
    x , y = 0, 0
    while len(queue) < n + 1:
        xvalue = 2 * queue[x] + 1
        yvalue = 3 * queue[y] + 1
        if xvalue < yvalue:
            if queue[-1] == xvalue:
                x += 1
                continue
            queue.append(xvalue)
            x += 1
        else:
            if queue[-1] == yvalue:
                y += 1
                continue
            queue.append(yvalue)
            y += 1

    return queue[n]
```

И эта:

```
def fib(n):
    v1, v2, v3 = 1, 1, 0    # initialise a matrix [[1,1],[1,0]]
    # perform fast exponentiation of the matrix (quickly raise it to the nth
    # power)
    for rec in bin(abs(n))[3:]:
        calc = v2 * v2
        v1, v2, v3 = v1 * v1 + calc, (v1 + v3) * v2, calc + v3 * v3
        if rec == '1':
            v1, v2, v3 = v1 + v2, v1, v2
    if n < 0:
        return v2 * ((-1) ** (abs(n) + 1))

    return v2 if n else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fib(n):  # Задаётся функция с названием fib которая принимает на вход один аргумент n
    v1, v2, v3 = 1, 1, 0    #переменным v1, v2, v3 задаются значения 1, 1, 0 соответственно

    for rec in bin(abs(n))[3:]: # начинается цикл для rec начиная со 2 символа бинарной записи числа n
        calc = v2 * v2 #calc = 1 * 1 
        v1, v2, v3 = v1 * v1 + calc, (v1 + v3) * v2, calc + v3 * v3 # v1 = (1 * 1) + 1, v2 = (1 + 0) * 1, v3 = 1 + 1 * 1.
        if rec == '1': #если rec это принимает значение 1, то
            v1, v2, v3 = v1 + v2, v1, v2 # v1 = 1 + 1, v2 = 1 , v3 = 1
    if n < 0: # если n<0 , то
        return v2 * ((-1) ** (abs(n) + 1)) # вернуть 1 * (-1 в степени (модуль n + 1)

    return v2 if n else 0
```